# Correlating between two sheets of excel using Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, list, dictionary

I am trying to take data from sheeet2 if sheet1 value matches with sheet2.

For example:

sheet1:

```
name    school
Rahul   DPS
Seema   KV
```

sheet2:

```
school_name profile       color       subject
DPS           1      orange,blue        math
DPS           2      red,purple        english
KV            1        yellow          science
```

if in sheet1 school matching with sheet2 school_name than take its all data ie. profile, color, subject.

For eg. sheet1 DPS matching with sheet2 DPS than output be like:

```
name= Rahul
school:{DPS:[{'profile':1,'color':orange,blue,'subject':math},{'profile':2,'color':red,purple,'subject':english}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't told us the rules of your excel column names I will assume they are unstructured and can change,

to get the matches between these two dataframes, we can use a series of `stack()` and boolean indexing

if this is your 2nd dataframe ;

```
print(df2)

  school_name  profile        color  subject
0         DPS        1  orange,blue     math
1         DPS        2   red,purple  english
2          KV        1       yellow  science
3         RDM        2          red  history


s = df2.stack().isin(df1.stack()).unstack()
df3 = df2.loc[s[s.eq(True)].dropna(how='all').index]

print(df3)

  school_name  profile        color  subject
0         DPS        1  orange,blue     math
1         DPS        2   red,purple  english
2          KV        1       yellow  science
```

you can then run your groupby operations.